# Javascript get Date() object from string time and date

Tags: javascript

I am programming a facebook chat bot and I receive the date and time from the user, I want to create an object of type Date().

Accepted formats from user:

Date:

```
15.9.2017
15/9/2017
15/09/2017
15.09.2017
```

Time:

```
15:30 et
15:30
3pm et
3pm
```

Would you recommend me some library (I've looked at moment.js)? How would you parse these formats?

**EDIT**

For **Time** validation I use this regex:

```
/((0?[0-9]{1,2} ?(pm|am) ?(et|at)?)|(0?[0-9]{1,2}:0?[0-9]{1,2} ?(pm) ?(et|at)?)|(0?[0-9]{1,2}:0?[0-9]{1,2} ?(et|at)?))/
```

For **Date** validation I use this regex:

```
/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-\.]\d{4}/
```

Comment: Use new Date(15/9/2017)  in case of dot (.) replace dot with ( '/' or '-')

Comment: no I need the time included and all of the formats

Comment: Are those all the accepted formats? Would 2016-12-25 be rejected?

Comment: for now yes... I am slovak guy and I am programming for american people, what time do they use in America? I will paste the regex which is used for validation.

Comment: Well, the date notation in the US usually has the month come first MM/DD/YYYY. Different from Europe.

Comment: @trincot ok thank you

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has quite limited date/time support, and it is generally recommended to use a library for any parsing requirements.

In my opinion, the defacto DateTime library for JavaScript it [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Using Moment.js, you can supply a date string like in your example, along with a format string which describes the format your date string is in.

For example:

```
var date = moment("15.9.2017", "D.M.YYYY");
```

For times you can use the H:m:s format string, and there is also a timezone extension for extra timezone manipulation.

All the docs are available at https://momentjs.com/docs/, the parsing section is here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

Comment: and what about time?